# Powershell Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, python-3.x, powershell-3.0

I am trying to run Powershell command from batch file test.bat. I am actually calling this command from Python Popen not from test.bat.(I am using test.bat just for validation)

```
powershell.exe (Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "SLOT 1" -DisplayName "Jumbo Packet").DisplayValue
```

Same command works with out second argument **-DisplayName "Jumbo Packet"** from python and batch

Error I get when I use second argument is below:

> Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty : A positional parameter cannot be
>   found that accepts argument '1'. At line:1 char:2
>   + (Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name SLOT 1 -DisplayName:Jumbo Packet).DisplayV ...
>   +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProp    erty], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Get-NetAdapterAdvanc    edProperty

*
But if I run the same command from Powershell window I get my expected result.

```
(Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "SLOT 1" -DisplayName "Jumbo Packet").DisplayValue
```

I am new to Powershell.Thanks for your help

Python code:

```
 iface="SLOT 1"   
 cmd= 'powershell.exe (Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "'+ iface +'" -DisplayName "Jumbo Packet").DisplayValue'
 conn.modules.os.popen(cmd).read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Brackets have special meaning in command. Escape them with a caret. The quotes may also need escaping with a caret.

But why the indirection. PS uses WMI. WMI is also available via COM. Python can do COM.

This is VBScript pulling out nics. You should be able to do this in any language that supports COM (nearly all).

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_NetworkAdaptor")

For Each objItem in colItems
    msgbox objitem.name 
Next
```

Comment: Thanks @trigger .. I am sorry like I said I am new to powershell and even for python. I am trying to verify the NIC adapter properties remotely. I am using rpyc connection to connect to my remote windows machine. I have to check how to get **objWMIService**  object of the remote machine. If that is achievable your solution is great. It gives better control rather than waiting for powershell output.Thanks again

Comment: 'c = wmi.WMI(ip, user=user, password=pwd,find_classes=False)
wql = "Select * From Win64_NetworkAdaptor"
        for item in c.query(wql):
            print item' I got to know how to connect to the WMI. Thanks. I will look WMI APIs now.

Comment: In VB the `.` here is the computer name (`\\.\root\cimv2`). `.` means local computer. You can put any computer name in for the `.`.

Comment: From command prompt use something like `wmic /node:"@%userprofile%\desktop\ComputerName.txt" /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\NicSpeed.html" /failfast:on nic where (PhysicalAdapter=TRUE and Speed!=100000000) get systemname,speed,caption /format:htable`

Answer (score 0):

Put double quotes around the whole command string (to make the entire command a string for CMD). Use single quotes inside the double-quoted string to define the nested strings for PowerShell:

```
powershell.exe "Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name 'SLOT 1' -DisplayName 'Jumbo Packet').DisplayValue"
```

Alternatively escape nested double quotes with backslashes:

```
powershell.exe "Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name \"SLOT 1\" -DisplayName \"Jumbo Packet\").DisplayValue"
```

However, in general it's less troublesome to simply put PowerShell commands in a script and run that script with PowerShell:

```
powershell.exe -File "C:\path\to\your.ps1"
```

Comment: Thanks.. This worked for me ..havent tried yours `conn.modules.subprocess.check_output(['powershell.exe','(Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty','-name "'+iface+'"','-DisplayName "Jumbo Packet").DisplayValue'])`

Comment: @Arjun Post an answer of your own then. The solution to your problem won't be helpful to anyone else if it's buried in a comment.